# Colorbar in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I got this script that produces the image below. However, when I put the plt.colorbar on the penultimate line, an error is produced which reads *No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation.* Why is that? Thanks in advance

'''

```
jet = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
cNorm = colors.Normalize(vmin=np.min(Mall), vmax=np.max(Mall))
scalarMap = cmx.ScalarMappable(norm=cNorm,cmap = jet)

x_fill1 = [0, 0, x[0, 1]]
y_fill1 = [0, 1, y[0, 1]]
x_fill4 = [x[0, n], x2[0, 1], 0]
y_fill4 = [y[0, n], y2[0, 1], 1]
x_fill8 = np.array([x[n-2, n-1], x[n-2, n], x[n-1, n]])
y_fill8 = np.array([y[n-2, n-1], y[n-2, n], y[n-1, n]])
plt.fill(x_fill1, y_fill1, color=scalarMap.to_rgba(Mall[0]))
plt.fill(x_fill4, y_fill4, color=scalarMap.to_rgba(Mall[n]))
plt.fill(x_fill8, y_fill8, color=scalarMap.to_rgba(Mall[int(n*(n+3) / 2 - 1)]))


for i in range(1,n):  # for n = 3 region 1 till 4
    colorVal = scalarMap.to_rgba(Mall[i])
    x_fill = [0., x[0, i], x[0, i + 1]]
    y_fill = [1., y[0, i], y[0, i + 1]]
    plt.fill(x_fill, y_fill, color=colorVal)

for i in range(n-2):  #
    colorVal = scalarMap.to_rgba(M[i + 1, i + 1])
    x_fill = np.array([x[i, i + 1], x[i, i + 2], x[i + 1, i + 2]])
    y_fill = np.array([y[i, i + 1], y[i, i + 2], y[i + 1, i + 2]])
    plt.fill(x_fill, y_fill, color=colorVal)
    for j in range(i+1, n-1):
        colorVal = scalarMap.to_rgba(M[i + 1, j + 1])
        x_fill = np.array([x[i, j + 1], x[i + 1, j + 1], x[i + 1, j + 2], x[i, j + 2]])
        y_fill = np.array([y[i, j + 1], y[i + 1, j + 1], y[i + 1, j + 2], y[i, j + 2]])
        plt.fill(x_fill, y_fill, color=colorVal)
        colorVal = scalarMap.to_rgba(M[i + 1, j])
        x_fill = np.array([x[i, j], x[i, j + 1], x[i + 1, j + 1]])
        y_fill = np.array([x[i, j], x[i, j + 1], x[i + 1, j + 1]])
        plt.fill(x_fill, y_fill, color=colorVal)


plt.ylim(0, 2.4)
#plt.colorbar(orientation='vertical', label='mach number')
plt.show()
```

'''

[image]

Comment: The code doesn't reproduce the image. Please clarify what *Mall* is. :)

Comment: The problem is that `plt.colorbar()` doesn't know which object you're referring to, and I think the challenge is that the colourbar needs to refer to various `plt.fill()` objects. So I think you can't just do `fill = plt.fill(...); plt.colorbar(fill)`, which would normally fix it.